# NamedQuery not returning result when property is null?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi there i seem to hit a wall when constructing my named query.

I have the following situation:
A Person has an optional Address and an Address has an optional Country.

Now i want to filter on a bunch of fields and return a result when
searching on some text.

I tried the following pieces, but whenever a Person has a location with and address and the address has no country then i get no results.

```
    filterOnAddress { String loc ->
        if(!loc.isEmpty()) {
            location {
                address {
                    or {
                        ilike 'street', "%${loc}%"
                        ilike 'city',  "%${loc}%"
                        country {
                            or {
                                ilike 'titleLocal',  "%${loc}%"
                                ilike 'title',  "%${loc}%"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
filterOnAddress { String loc ->
    if(!loc.isEmpty()) {
        location {
            address {
                or {
                    ilike 'street', "%${loc}%"
                    ilike 'city',  "%${loc}%"
                    and {
                        isNotNull('country')
                        country {
                            or {
                                ilike 'titleLocal',  "%${loc}%"
                                ilike 'title',  "%${loc}%"
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the Country is null for the Person the query does not return
the expected result as according to my knowledge some criteria are
met! So i would expect some results when a country is null.

What do i need to have in my query when country is null but the other
criteria are succesfull?

Comment: can you construct a plain SQL query for that scenario? Maybe that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty legit to me from a quick scan.  I'd recommend removing country section and making sure you're getting data without it.  Then my next step would be to turn on sql logging (add logSql element to datasource, per http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource), and see what's being used to seek out the data.